# How to provide power supply to PCB?

Tags: power-supply, pcb

This PCB is supposed to have 12-15V and 0.5A of current. How I should provide power to it? As I understand `+V`(as +) and `OUT`(as -) are places where power should be. Could I buy some adapter and solder plug for it? But there seems to be no place for it...

[image: Move detector PCB]

Detailed scheme:

[image]

General view:

[image]

Comment: Power is supplied throuh V+ and the spot marked with an upside down "T" just below the V+.

Comment: @JRE this PCB is move detector. It is a kit. I'll provide detailed scheme of it in description.

Comment: As long as it can be used in real world I thought that it would need suitable power supply, that will just fit in, but I basically have no idea....

Comment: The kit instructions should tell you how to connect and use the board - if not, ask the supplier for more information.

Comment: Looks like the output is floating. You need a pull  up resistor to the 12V line from OUT.

Answer (score 1):

I'll use something similar to this 12V power block

[image]

There are two options here:

1. Find appropriate plug and solder it to PCB(as I stated in my original description)
2. In case I cannot find such plug, I'll just extract wires, find where are `+` and `-` and solder them appropriately to PCB

(these options are based on call to manufacturer's support)

Answer (score 0):

If the scheme you provide is right, then V+ is the +12V (+) and T (the ground plane of the board) is the GND (-).

This can be confirmed by the scheme, as the emitter (E) of transistor VT2 is connected to GND and PCB shows a path from E to the ground plane.

DON'T connect the GND to OUT.

At the real PCB I can see some holes with the corresponding markings OUT, T and V+ should be in the adjacent region. So you can buy a 12-15V power supply, cut the terminal and solder the wires right upon the board.